# How can I upgrade specific packages using pip and a requirements file?

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip

I'm using pip with a requirements file, in a virtualenv, for my Django projects.  I'm trying to upgrade some packages, notably Django itself, and I'm getting an error about source code conflicts:

> Source in `<virtualenv`>/build/Django has version 1.2.3 that conflicts with Django==1.2.4 (from -r requirements/apps.txt (line 3))

That's after updating the version number of Django from 1.2.3 to 1.2.4 in my requirements file.  I'm using this command to actually do the upgrade:

```
pip --install --upgrade -E `<virtualenv dir`> --requirement `<requirements file`>
```

I can't find any flag that triggers a total package re-download.  I even tried running an uninstall command first, and then the install, but no dice. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please check @dr-jimbob 's answer because recent versions of pip will actually upgrade all other dependencies that the package you are upgrading depends on.

Comment: @gcaprio I'd rather advice you to choose marcin swierczynski answer now

Comment: In an app that has a `Django` backend and `Angular` frontend, should the `requirements.txt` file be in the root directory (and run there with `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt`) or should it be in the backend folder where files such as `manage.py` are located?

Comment: Every so often you get a message from pip itself, asking you to upgrade it and it gives you the command to do so. So just use the same command but for another package.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

First make sure you have checked [the most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440459/2436175).

---

I'm not sure if it's exactly your problem, but in my case, I wasn't able to upgrade Django to 1.2.4 - I was always finishing with 1.2.3 version, so I uninstalled Django with:

```
<virtualenv>/bin/pip uninstall Django
```

Then I removed `<virtualenv>/build/Django` directory and finally I installed the proper version with:

```
<virtualenv>/bin/pip install Django
```

Comment: This is not the best practice. Use `pip install Django -U` or `pip install Django --upgrade` as described in @JoeyG 's answer.

Comment: @Ahmad agree. There should be a smooth update process in pip and virtual env.

Answer (score 1660):

I ran the following command and it upgraded from 1.2.3 to 1.4.0

```
pip install Django --upgrade
```

Shortcut for upgrade:

```
pip install Django -U
```

**Note**: if the package you are upgrading has any requirements this command will additionally upgrade all the requirements to the latest versions available.  In recent versions of pip, [you can prevent this behavior by specifying `--upgrade-strategy only-if-needed`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption--upgrade-strategy).  With that flag, dependencies will not be upgraded unless the installed versions of the dependent packages no longer satisfy the requirements of the upgraded package.

Comment: This for me updated all my packaged and totally messed up everything!!!! Documents states: --upgrade all packages to the newest available version. Is this correct or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @OrbiterFleet I needed to update "requests" so I did `pip install Requests --upgrade` and *only* "requests" was upgraded.  The description says "upgrade all *specified* packages" when I view the docs.

Comment: ATTENTION, it also **updates all dependencies** and can mess up with everything. the best option is to uninstall and reinstall the package.

Comment: to upgrade specific package use `pip install --upgrade django==1.4.0`

Comment: this should be the right answer according to question or the question itself is wrong.

Comment: Is that the proper syntax highlight for the command lines (*not* a rhetorical question)?

Comment: `pip install -U <package>` and `pip install --upgrade <package>` are also valid syntax

Comment: If you are using `pipenv` you run the command `pipenv update PackageName`

Answer (score 80):

According to pip [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html) example 3:

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

But based on my experience, using this method will also upgrade any package related to it. Example:

Assume you want to upgrade `somepackage` that require `Django >= 1.2.4` using this kind of method it will also upgrade `somepackage` *and* `django` to the newest update. Just to be safe, do:

```
# Assume you want to keep Django 1.2.4
pip install --upgrade somepackage django==1.2.4
```

Doing this will upgrade `somepackage` and keeping Django to the 1.2.4 version.

Comment: Good catch but your explanation is confusing since you started with `django` as a main package then in the example you use `somepackage` and then use `django` as a dependency.

Comment: Yes it should be `pip install --upgrade django==1.2.4` without the "somepackage"

Answer (score 42):

The shortcut command for `--upgrade`:

```
pip install Django --upgrade
```

Is:

```
pip install Django -U
```

Comment: How about editing the existing answer to add this bit of information instead of an (incomplete) answer?

Comment: @a1an please suggest what extra info that you think should be added in a "suggested edit". Thanks

Comment: I mean you could edit the answer given by JoeyG, adding the shortcut option you provided in context there.

Answer (score 29):

If you only want to upgrade one specific package called `somepackage`, the command you should use in recent versions of pip is

```
pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed somepackage
```

This is very useful when you develop an application in Django that currently will only work with a specific version of Django (say Django=1.9.x) and want to upgrade some dependent package with a bug-fix/new feature and the upgraded package depends on Django (but it works with, say, any version of Django after 1.5).

The default behavior of `pip install --upgrade django-some-package` would be to upgrade Django to the latest version available which could otherwise break your application, though with the `--upgrade-strategy only-if-needed` dependent packages will now only be upgraded as necessary.

Answer (score 18):

If you upgrade a package, the old one will be uninstalled.

A convenient way to do this is to use this [pip-upgrader](https://github.com/simion/pip-upgrader) which also updates the versions in your `requirements.txt` file for the chosen packages (or all packages).

**Installation**

```
pip install pip-upgrader
```

**Usage**

Activate your [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (important, because it will also install the new versions of upgraded packages in current virtualenv).

`cd` into your project directory, and then run:

```
pip-upgrade
```

**Advanced usage**

If the requirements are placed in a non-standard location, send them as arguments:

```
pip-upgrade path/to/requirements.txt
```

If you already know what package you want to upgrade, simply send them as arguments:

```
pip-upgrade -p django -p celery -p dateutil
```

If you need to upgrade to  pre-release / post-release version, add `--prerelease` argument to your command.

Full disclosure: I wrote this package.

Comment: is there an option to upgrade all packages at once (ie, without listing them) with this approach?

Comment: @MikePalmice yes: `pip-upgrade -p all` will upgrade all your packages and update requirements file without needing any input from you.

Comment: Doesn't fork for me. Helped finally: pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade

Answer (score 15):

This solved the issue for me:

```
pip install -I --upgrade psutil --force
```

Afterwards just uninstall psutil with the new version and hop you can suddenly install the older version (:

Answer (score 8):

Defining a specific version to upgrade helped me instead of only the upgrade command.

```py
pip3 install larapy-installer==0.4.01 -U
```

Comment: this works for me Python 3.8.1

Answer (score 4):

Normally, pip will clean up after itself and remove the contents of the build directory. The only time it doesn't do this is if:

1. You used the `--no-install` option
2. You are using editable packages
3. The installation was cancelled or was otherwise interrupted.

In all other cases, you shouldn't have `build` directory that's clogging your environment.

Answer (score 3):

to upgrade your package

```
pip install --upgrade YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME==VERSION
```

from requirement file

```
pip install --upgrade -r requiremnet.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
pip3 install -r  requirements.txt
```