# Can I use a later of version of sqlite3 with python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python 3.5.1 which comes with an sqlite version of 3.8.11. I wonder if I could use another version of sqlite (say the [latest one](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_10_2.html) as of now) with my current python. If the answer is yes then how do I do that? Learning from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440459/3375713) I tried this but it does not do anything:

```
pip install sqlite3 --upgrade
```

I am using sqlite3 in my django project that needs full-text search. So I was reading [this](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html), and at a point I was *tempted* to use the [latest version](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_10_2.html) of sqlite3 as it said it had some improvements over the previous versions, which seemed interesting to me. Anyway, is it possible to use later version of sqlite3 without upgrading python?

---

**Note:** the question is almost completely re-written, so many comments may seem irrelevant. Thanks to [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair), I came to know that the previous question didn't make any sense, hence I re-wrote it.

Comment: sqlite3 is part of the Python *installation*, not an external library, so it's not upgradeable using pip. I'm not sure whether sqlite3 is upgradeable without upgrading to a new version of Python. Doing a quick google search suggests that some people have tried replacing dll files. That is Windows specific, and it seems very hacky to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some googling I found a way to do this. You need to download the `sqlite3.dll` (pre-compiled binary) file from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Then copy over this file in the `DLLs` folder in the python installation directory. You may want to make a backup of your old `sqlite3.dll` file just in case you may decide to revert.

Comment: I've came up to the same solution but now the question is "is it possible to load this dll not from DLL folder"?

Comment: @SergeNorin I am not sure, but somehow I don't think so. I think where to read DLLs from is something built into python. But who knows!

Comment: But what if on a Linux machine?

Comment: @hanson don't know how to do the same on a Linux machine. If you happen to find a way, do post as an answer.