# Update SQLite 3.21 to 3.24+ in Python Lib

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, upsert

I am a beginner at python and SQL. I have an [upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) clause to my SQL command but my Python [SQLite standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html) is running on sqlite v3.21 which does not support **upsert** syntax. The upsert clause only works on SQLite v3.24 and above.

```
# UPSERT syntax established by PostSQL, Inputs data into SQLite database
c1.executemany("INSERT INTO result(_time,src_ip) VALUES(?,?) ON "
               "CONFLICT(src_ip) DO UPDATE SET Count=Count+1;", to_db)
```

I tried `pip install --upgrade pysqlite`,`pip install --upgrade sqlite3`, and many other commands but it did not update my SQLite Library. It seems Python 3.7.1 does not support SQLite v3.24 and above.

Is there a way to update Python3 SQLite library to v3.24? Is there a way I can download sqlite v3.24+ package to import it to my script?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a full solution, as it doesn't solve the problem in stock Python, but Anaconda's sqlite package is at 3.26.0 when I updated Python today, meaning I can take advantage of it. Modifying the stock Python likely will take some plumbing. Maybe there's a Conda-forge or similar recipe that can help?

Comment: Oh! [There's already an answer to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35011654/786020) It's for Python 3.5, but it may be the same for Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem..

I replace sqlite3.dll in c:/python3/DLLs