# ImportError: cannot import name 'UnstructuredExcelLoader' from 'langchain.document_loaders'

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, python-import

I am getting the following errors when trying to run a cloned repo of localGPT on my mac.  I have successfully installed everything in the requirements.txt file.

This is happening with multiple python repos and other imports. Is this a path issue?  How might I fix those.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Documents/GitHub/localGPT/ingest.py", line 12, in <module>
    from constants import (CHROMA_SETTINGS, DOCUMENT_MAP, EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, INGEST_THREADS, PERSIST_DIRECTORY,
  File "/Documents/GitHub/localGPT/constants.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain.document_loaders import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'UnstructuredExcelLoader' from 'langchain.document_loaders' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/__init__.py)
```

I have run this in Coda, through the terminal app, and in VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "`"cannot import name 'UnstructuredExcelLoader' from 'langchain.document_loaders'"`", I found [Closed
ImportError: cannot import name 'UnstructuredExcelLoader' from 'langchain.document_loaders' #113](https://github.com/PromtEngineer/localGPT/issues/113). Quoting from [a comment by @ashokrs there](https://github.com/PromtEngineer/localGPT/issues/113#issuecomment-1582723985):

> The UnstructuredExcelLoader module was removed from one of the earlier versions of the langchain library. Sorry, I don't know which one specifically. If you are using an older version of the library, you will need to upgrade to a newer version in order to use the UnstructuredExcelLoader module.
>
> Not only this error you had come across so far, You may need to carefully run "pip install -r requirements.txt" to update many python libraries to factor in all the changes since your recent pull. Please see that the "requirements.txt" is also changed yesterday.

I believe you can upgrade using `pip install langchain --upgrade`. For some reason, @ashokrs suggested instead to do `pip uninstall langchain` and then `pip install langchain`. I'm not sure what the difference is. See also [How can I upgrade specific packages using pip and a requirements file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4536103/11107541).

Comment: Uninstalling worked.  Also helped to specify the python version when setting up the conda environment 

`conda create --name local-gpt python=3.11.3 `

Answer (score 2):

If your issue doesn't get resolved with `pip install langchain --upgrade` or
`pip uninstall langchain` and then `pip install langchain`.

Just Restart your IDE, mostly it will solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me